# ArnoldiMethod.jl and symmetric matrices

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, hpc, eigenvalue

I am testing ArnoldiMethod.jl for a generalised eigenvalue problem with symmetric sparse matrices. The following code, modified from the example in the documentation of ArnoldiMethod.jl, works fine.

```
using ArnoldiMethod, LinearAlgebra, LinearMaps, SparseArrays

# Define the matrices of the generalized eigenvalue problem
n = 100
A, B = sprand(Float64,n,n, 0.05), sprand(Float64,n,n, 0.05)

[A[i,i]=1.0 for i in 1:A.m]
[B[i,i]=1.0 for i in 1:B.m]

struct ShiftAndInvert{TA,TB,TT}
    A_lu::TA
    B::TB
    temp::TT
end

function (M::ShiftAndInvert)(y,x)
    mul!(M.temp, M.B, x)
    ldiv!(y, M.A_lu, M.temp)
end

function construct_linear_map(A,B)
    a = ShiftAndInvert(factorize(A),B,Vector{eltype(A)}(undef, size(A,1)))
    LinearMap{eltype(A)}(a, size(A,1), ismutating=true)
end

# Target the largest eigenvalues of the inverted problem
decomp,  = partialschur(construct_linear_map(A, B), nev=4, tol=1e-5, restarts=100, which=LM())
λs_inv, X = partialeigen(decomp)

# Eigenvalues have to be inverted to find the smallest eigenvalues of the non-inverted problem.
λs = 1 ./ λs_inv

# Show that Ax = Bxλ
@show norm(A * X - B * X * Diagonal(λs)) # 2.8043149027575927e-6
```

Problems arise when I define the matrices as symmetric:

```
using ArnoldiMethod, LinearAlgebra, LinearMaps

# Define the matrices of the generalized eigenvalue problem
n = 100
A, B = Symmetric(sprand(Float64,n,n, 0.05),:L), Symmetric(sprand(Float64,n,n, 0.05),:L)

[A.data[i,i]=1.0 for i in 1:A.data.m]
[B.data[i,i]=1.0 for i in 1:B.data.m]
```

The root cause of the problem seems to be ldiv!(), which is not compatible with the type SuiteSparse.CHOLMOD.Factor{Float64}. The only alternative I found so far is calling another time sparse() on the matrices and treating them as not symmetric, and by using lu() instead of factorize() during the call of ShiftAndInvert(), but this makes the algorithm slower than eigs() from Arpack.jl. Is there any workaround?